# python - best way to add a long text below plots and save this into a pdf

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, computer-vision

I have a large set of photos, in which I detected several objects in every photo. I want to create a pdf including all photos and the name of the identified object, written below (not within) each photo. As there are many photos which have many objects I cannot write it within the photo or use a legend / axis name to include them. What would you suggest as best approach / library in python or other language for this problem?

Comment: Would the `text` function from matplotlib do what you are looking for?

Comment: I think with matplotlib I am only able to put text inside a plot or in a legend or as an axis value. I would like to generate an image where several lines of text are written below the plot.

Answer (score 1):

@Entropie_13, just addressing here your comment with an example. You can use the `text`function from matplotlib to put the text of any length wherever you want on the figure. Below is an example with text on each side of the figure.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
fig=plt.figure()
N_points=10
x=np.arange(N_points)
y=np.arange(N_points)
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.xlabel('x-axis')
plt.ylabel('y-axis')
text_example='Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.\n Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. \n Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.\n Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.'
plt.text(-3,-8,text_example)
plt.text(-25,3.5,text_example)
plt.text(-3,16,text_example)
plt.text(25,3.5,text_example)
plt.savefig('fig_caption.pdf')
```

The code save the figure as a pdf and the output looks like that:

[image]

Comment: thx for your effort. Since I want to automatically put texts with different lengths / number of lines below different plots, I tried to figer out the relationship between number of lines and the position argument in plt.text , but it is quite difficult using something like  ```plt.text(-3, -constant - len(text_example), `text_example``` . Do you have an idea how I could do this, so the text does not accidentally covers the plot or is too far below?